# Get current page absolute url

Tags: application-pages, url

I want to get the current page absolute url in sharepoint..
I'm using:

```
this.Page.Request.Url.ToString()
```

But for:

http://e-albania.tirana.bz:6002/sites/ealbania02/_layouts/IISNewsBox/news_view.aspx

it returns

http://e-albania.tirana.bz:6002/_layouts/IISNewsBox/news_view.aspx

Maybe cause layouts folder is the same for all the web applications..
How do I get the correct url?

Comment: Have you tried `Page.Request.RawUrl`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code below should do the trick

```
Page.Request.RawUrl
```

Comment: Great! Though it only gives you the relative URL without the `http://domain/` part

Answer (score 3):

HttpContext.Current.Request.Url

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701309/get-app-relative-url-from-request-url-absolutepath

or

SPSite.MakeFullUrl()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.makefullurl.aspx

an example is:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://e-albania.tirana.bz"))
{     using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      string absoluteURL = site.MakeFullUrl(this.Page.Request.Url.ToString());
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: The time-battle forced you to update the answer? :)  In any case very nice. +1

Comment: well what can i say it a race against the time and I wanted to make sure he had a selection to choose from instead of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url lol.

Comment: Thanx but I don't know why HttpContext.Current.Request.Url doesn't work, instead Page.Request.RawUrl did it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

It should give you the current pages url.

Comment: it doesn't give you the url including subsites - maybe sharepoints custom iis pipeline at work